How to position text below three columns of images
I am trying to lay out three images horizontally and display text across the page below the images. The text is appearing at the top of the page. All three images are wrapped in an enclosing div. The text appears at the top f the page. How do I make the outer div reserve space so that the following text appears below it?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
    <!--
        .column {
          width: 55%;
          padding: 5px;
          }

        .row::after {
          content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: table-row;
            font-size: x-large;
            }
        img {
          width:60%; max-width:60%;
            }
        a   {font-size: x-large;}
        p   {font-size: x-large;}
    -->
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="column" style="position:absolute; left:0;">
              <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Goebbels">
                  <img src="../images/Bundesarchiv_Bild_146-1968-101-20A,_Joseph_Goebbels.jpg"
                       alt="image of Joeseph Goebbels at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bundesarchiv_Bild_146-1968-101-20A,_Joseph_Goebbels.jpg">
                  <p style="position:relative; left:15%;">
                  Joseph Goebbels
                  </p>
              </a>
          </div>
          <div class="column" style="position:absolute; left:33%; top:15%;">
              <img src="../images/768px-Republican_Disc.svg.png"
                   alt="Image of GOP elephant at https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/93/Republican_Disc.svg/768px-Republican_Disc.svg.png">
          </div>
          <div class="column" style="position:absolute; left:66%">
              <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Putin">
                  <img src="../images/Vladimir_Putin_(2018-03-01)_03_(cropped).jpg"
                       alt="Image of Vladimir Putin at https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Vladimir_Putin_%282018-03-01%29_03_%28cropped%29.jpg">
                  <p style="position:relative; left:15%;">
                  Vladimir Putin
                  </p>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>

      <p style="text-align: center; font-size: xx-large;">
      Party of Treason
      </p>
      <p style="text-align: center; font-size: large;">
      January 6, 2021, a day that shal live in infamy
      </p>

  </body>
</html>



